# How do I remove duplicate in array and bring count?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am accessing array which is in loop through:

`var author = $$('.author').map(e=>e.textContent);`

I want this to remove duplicate from array from authors list and fetch count and display on the front end. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: Adiga has a point. And I also feel I should not have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a set then back to an array:

```
[... new Set(author)];
```

Comment: Please vote to close obvious duplicates instead of answering them